# Good textbooks on optimization to read?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, programming

I am a user of CPLEX and I routinely came across more or less theoretical issues in my work. So I have to keep improving my optimization skills and knowledge. So far I have finished two well known optimization books.

1. Convex Optimization by Boyd and Vandenberghe
2. Introduction to Linear Optimization by Bertsimas and Tsitsiklis.

I am wondering what kind of books I should read next? I think probably integer programming or non-linear programming might be the next. But I am not sure about it. My goal is to become an expert CPLEX or Gurobi user. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Integer Programming material of some kind.  But you said you "finished" two books. What does finished mean?  Did you solve or at least seriously attempt to solve many of the exercises? That's how you really learn the material and gain a facility with it.